# update manager not updating

Tags: package-management, thunderbird

every time i run update manager, i get a message saying

"The package system is broken

If you are using third party repositories then disable them, since they are a common source of problems.
Now run the following command in a terminal: apt-get install -f"

I run this command in a terminal, but nothing happens...this started happening since i installed a calender plugin for thunderbird. is this the cause?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get purge thunderbird; sudo apt-get install thunderbird
```

Comment: Hi, sorry about the delay in replying, but what you suggested worked a treat! thank you very much!

Comment: if it worked please mark the answer as correct